# How do I find .bash_profile and add to my shell's initialization file?

Tags: rvm

I am trying to upgrade ruby using rvm.
On the [pragmatic site](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac), it says:

> The important part is to add the following line to the end of your shell's initialization file (.bash_profile):
>
> `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

How do I do this? Where is this initialization file?
Please help

Answer (score 6):

It would be `/home/$USER/.bash_profile`, but would only be present if you're actually using bash as your shell. Other shells will use a 'dot file' with their name in them instead. You can view them with `ls -ad $HOME/.*`

Comment: Still confused marc: here's what I get when I add that line:

Comment: $HOME is an environment variable which by convention has the path to your account's home directory. If your username is `amit`, then the bash file would be in `/home/amit/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

There are two initialization files .bash_profile & .bashrc, both present in user home directory.

.bash_profile is initialized when you login with userid. .bashrc is initialized when you are already logged in and want to open one more terminal.

If you want to add some settings in both the file then you can do following

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];
 then
source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: I can find neither .bash_profile & .bashrc in my home directory - also did a system wide search for these. And yes, I can see invisible files.

Comment: which OS and version are you using ?

Comment: What you can do is to search for just *profile* keyword in pattern search ....in case you don't find any file...just create one and add it the the lines that you want to.

Comment: I created my own bash_profile and now it works