# Can't find .bash_profile in my home directory

Tags: bash, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find .bash_profile and add to my shell's initialization file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227565/how-do-i-find-bash-profile-and-add-to-my-shells-initialization-file)

I can't find this file: .bash_profile. I am trying to upgrade ruby via rvm and I need to add rvm to every new shell window that opens. But I can't find .bash_profile anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple shell script, just create it and fill it with the desired content.

`man bash` describes for which (initialization) files Bash looks under what circumstances and in which order it does it for your particular Bash version.

Comment: agreed. .bashrc is normally automatically created on Debian, but .bash_profile needs to be created "by hand".